# What does create_list refer to in Tastypie's custom authorisation?

Tags: python, django, authorization, tastypie

I've been studying the [Tastypie API documentation for custom authorisation](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/authorization.html).

There are eight possible methods to implement to create a custom authorisation class.

- `read_list`
- `read_detail`
- `create_list`
- `create_detail`
- `update_list`
- `update_detail`
- `delete_list`
- `delete_detail`

I am really struggling to understand the semantics of each of these methods. How exactly do they correspond to HTTP verbs (GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE... etc.)?

Initially, I thought that the `*_list` methods might mean...

> Give me a list of all objects that the user can [create, read, update, delete]

But the "create" case...

> Give me a list of all objects that the user can **create**

...really doesn't make sense, since the objects have already been created. In order to make sense with my interpretation, this would have to be a list of all possible objects the user *could* create (which is clearly infeasible).

So what does `create_list` actually mean? What about `create_detail` and how does it differ to `create_list`?

Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is about philosophy and concepts, and there are actually 3 questions, but let me try to answer you question briefly.

---

## *_list vs *_detail:

***_list** methods are filters of objects user has an access to.

***_detail** methods are booleans that tell us, whether we can have an access to the exact object.

**Example:**

**read_list** - filters objects, that user will see on **site.com/api/v1/cool_object/**

**read_detail** - tells us whether user is allowed to view **site.com/api/v1/cool_object/2**

---

## Mapping CRUD to HTTP (Tastypie):

**CREATE** - **POST**

**READ** - **GET**

**UPDATE** - **PUT** (to upload new entity) / **PATCH** (to send changed fields only)

**DELETE** - **DELETE**

---

## Why create_list:

The method was added just for the sake of uniformity and consistency. So you were right to see no practical sense in it.

We can even check it in the [tastypie/authorization.py](https://github.com/django-tastypie/django-tastypie/blob/master/tastypie/authorization.py#L45):

> ```
> def create_list(self, object_list, bundle):
>     """
>     Unimplemented, as Tastypie never creates entire new lists, but
>     present for consistency & possible extension.
>     """
> ```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer, you've covered all the main points! The comments in the source code really ought to be in the documentation too.